# SiS tourney A050 thumb 1x7 to either a 1x10 or 2x7

Tags: road-bike

So I have this cheaper end roadbike sporting a Tourney A050 sis shifters (I don't know what they are called, they are those roadbike shifters sitting on the horizontal handle bar) 1x7, quite a pain. I am quite a noob at upgrading so I wanted your help. I wanted to know: is it possible and how to upgrade to a Deore 1x10? Along with the shifter the cassette and the derailleur do I need to change the wheel and chain too? And is it possible to shift to an integrated brake shifters of any kind? Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear whether you have drop bars or a flat bar. Normally 'roadbike' would strongly imply drop style handlebars, but you talk about 'horizontal' bars and are thinking about upgrading to Deore which is a mountain bike groupset. 'Integrated shifters' would normally mean shifters for a drop bar as mountain bikes have moved to separate shifter and brake units. However, the answer is the same.

If you have a 7 speed cluster of sprockets on the rear wheel, you either have an old-style 7 speed *freewheel* or a 7 speed *freehub* and cassette. See [here](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/freewheels.html) for a description of the difference. In either case you will not be able to upgrade to 10 sprockets on the hub. Freewheels only go up to 7 speeds; the freehub body for 7 speeds is slightly shorter that those used for 8, 9 and 10 speeds and cannot accomodate a 10 speed cassette. To get 10 speeds in the rear you would need a new rear wheel with a 10 speed compatible freehub. You would then be able to fit a 10 speed road or mountain groupset. However, at this point you are looking at replacing more than half the bike, so it probably makes more economic sense to look for a used bike with a 1x10 or 2x10 drivetrain.

If you are prepared to stay at 7 speeds in the rear things are a bit easier. the Shimano Tourney line has 3x7 speed shifters for flat bars, Microshift makes Shimano compatible  3x7 road bike integrated shifters/brakes I believe. You could use derailleurs from Shimano's lines above Tourney as 7, 8 and 9 speed derailleurs all use the same actuation ratio.

Obviously for 10 speed you'd need a 10 speed compatible chain, but if you stick with 7 speed I'd replace the freewheel or cassette and chain as well so you have a complete new drivetrain.

Comment: Thx argenti apparatus,I was talking about the horizontal hold of the drop bars.Usually shifters on road bikes are integrated  with the brakes but theses ones are placed on the horizontal hold of the drop bars.U were right about everything else it's not a good option to upgrade to 1x10 . I rather change the bike

Comment: My first road bike had the same A050 shifters. I guess you would call them stem shifters? They mount to the tops of drop bars, right on either side of the stem.

Comment: @MaplePanda No, stem shifters literally mount to the stem, and look like down tube shifters.   OP seems to have flat bar shifters that are on the tops of some drop-bars.

Answer (score 0):

I've dome something similar, upspeccing a 3x5 speed MTB to 3x9 deore.

The parts came to me free because they were salvaged from a wrecked frame.  All I needed was new cables and grips, and a set of spokes.

I had to rebuild my 26" wheel onto a hub that was sized to take a 8/9/10 speed cassette, and this needed different length spokes.

The cassette, derailleur, and chain all slotted in nicely, and there was enough chain off the donor bike to reach.   I did NOT replace my front chainrings or front derailleur - they're still for 5 speed width chain.   I did have to spread the rear dropouts and re-align them to be parallel, so a steel frame was mandatory.

If your frame's OLD is not 135mm, AND its not steel, then give up at this point.  You should not stretch any aluminium frame or anything not steel.

In your case, you need to price up the costs of all the parts, and then see if that is more or less than the cost of a replacement bike.   Also that your bike will be out of operation for at least a day while the upgrade is being installed.  You will need at a minimum

- Right hand 10 speed Shifter
- 10 speed chain
- 10 speed derailleur
- 10 speed cassette

You probably want also new grips/bartape because the old stuff tends to suffer when removed.   Also use new inner/outer gear cable because there's little saving in reusing the old stuff.   I would suggest keeping the shifter and derailleur from the same groupset, and don't go too far outside the specifications of the derailleur when choosing a cassette.

---

If your current shifter is combined with the brake lever, then you will need a separate right-hand brake lever as well.  Integrated tends to decrease your options, so get separate parts for future convenience.